# Using CircuitPython to send a value to a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to communicate with a Sony camera and trigger it over BLE through an ESP32-S3 running CircuitPython using adafruit libraries.

According to the documentation I found, I need to write the value "0x0107" to the characteristic "0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" on the service "8000ff00-ff00-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"

I seem to be able to connect to the camera, unfortunately I can't seem to find the way to write to the custom service/characteristic.

I've tried using different formats for the UUIDs and ways to obtain the handlers for the required objects.
The line that sets the value fails.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ble
from adafruit_ble.advertising.standard import ProvideServicesAdvertisement
from adafruit_ble.services.standard.device_info import DeviceInfoService
from adafruit_ble.uuid import VendorUUID, UUID
SERVICE = "8000ff00-ff00-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff" 
# CHARACTERISTIC = "0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
CHARACTERISTIC = "0xff01"
# Set up the BLE radio
ble = adafruit_ble.BLERadio()
COM1 = 0x0107
COM1A= bytes([0x01, 0x07])
COM2 = 0x0109
COM3 = 0x0108
COM4 = 0x0106


# Create the advertisement object
advertisement = ProvideServicesAdvertisement()

# Start advertising the services
ble.start_advertising(advertisement)

# Scan for the Sony a6100 camera and connect to it
while True:
    print("Scanning for Sony a6100 camera...")
    for device in ble.start_scan(timeout=5):
        if device.complete_name == "ILCE-6100":
            print("Found Sony a6100 camera, connecting...")
            connection = ble.connect(device)
            break
    ble.stop_scan()
    time.sleep(1)

    # Once connected, send the necessary commands to the camera to pair
    while not ble.connected:
      pass  
    print("Paired with Sony a6100 camera!")
    
    
    #dis = connection[DeviceInfoService]
    dis = connection[VendorUUID(SERVICE)]
    service_handler = connection._discovered_bleio_services[VendorUUID(SERVICE)]
    print("discovered:", service_handler)
    characteristics_handler = service_handler.characteristics
    for characteristic in characteristics_handler:
        print("CH:", type(characteristic), "|", characteristic, "uuid:", str(characteristic.uuid))
        if str(characteristic.uuid) == ("UUID("+CHARACTERISTIC+")"):
          print("CHARACTERISTIC FOUND")
          characteristic_handler=characteristic
    print("Sending commands")
    characteristic_handler.value(COM1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The UUIDs for the service and characteristic look a little unusual for a commercial product. Have you tried using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to validate those UUIDs and the values that need to be written?

Comment: They're custom UUIDs but I found them in several sources and also confirmed them using nRF Connect indeed. I managed to conect and trigger the camera using nRF connect and these values.
My problem is how to use the libraries (or how to do it in general) to send the value to that custom service/characteristic. I seem to be able to get a valid handler for the service and characteristic, so I assume this part is also working on my circuitpython code. Thanks dor the nRF tip though!It's a very useful piece of software  :)

Comment: Indeed,but that syntax you proposed doesn't seem to be correct, and there's no "write" function that I can find. So that's my problem.I tried sending all values defined in the code as COMx, as those are the commands that I need to get through.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar, trying to connect an nRf52840 board to a Sony Camera via BLE. Just looking over your code and my guess is that you didn't pair with the Camera before writing to the characteristics. Try calling `connection.pair()` after `connection = ble.connect(device)`

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).